# Why don't items expire in my Micronaut/Redis cache?

Tags: java, caching, redis, micronaut

I have a Micronaut cache in Redis configured like this:

```yaml
redis:
  uri: ${REDIS_URL:`redis://localhost`}
  caches:
    kyc-fenergo-service-token:
      expire-after-write: 14m
```

I have a method annotated like this: `@Cacheable(value = "kyc-fenergo-service-token")`

After the first call, the value is cached as expected, but it never expires. Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: Check your Redis server configuration to ensure that key expiration is enabled. Look for the notify-keyspace-events configuration directive in your Redis configuration file (redis.conf) and make sure it includes the Ex flag. For example, notify-keyspace-events Ex.

Comment: @OlesiaIlchuk  Thanks, it worked! If you add you comment as an answer, I will mark it as the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your Redis server configuration to ensure that key expiration is enabled. Look for the `notify-keyspace-events` configuration directive in your Redis configuration file (`redis.conf`) and make sure it includes the Ex flag. For example, `notify-keyspace-events Ex`.